# ASP.NET - Download File When File Name Contain slash /

Tags: asp.net, http, url

I am trying to download a file whose filename contains a date formatted as dd/MM/yyyy (for example, the expected file name would be MyFile - 22/07/2020.pdf), but the downloaded file becomes MyFile - 22_07_2020.pdf.

Below is my code

```
var filename = Server.UrlDecode("MyFile -" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".pdf"); //which shows MyFile - 22%2f07%2f2020.pdf in debugger
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

How should I modify to get the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the forward slash in a filename, as `/` implies that you are referencing a directory. Try to use a different character, or use a unicode character that looks like a slash but isn't.

Comment: Actually both forward and backward aren't supported in filenames